# Cant pass arguments to perl script using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, perl

I'm trying to do what should be a simple action-- execute a perl script from within a python3 script, passing several arguments to the perl script. Here's what I've tried, nothing works:

Approach 1 -- the perl script runs, but the arguments aren't passed

```
addexec = "../perl/bin/engine.pl"
addvars = " --uid " + str(our_id) + " --url '" + source_url + "'"
addtodb = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/perl", addexec, addvars])
```

Approach 2 -- the perl script doesn't run, says file not found

```
addexec = "../perl/bin/engine.pl --uid " + str(our_id) + " --url '" + source_url
addtodb = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/perl", addexec])
```

Approach 3 -- the perl script doesn't run, generates errors

```
addcmd = ["/usr/bin/perl", "../perl/bin/engine.pl", " --uid ", str(our_id), " --url '", source_url, "'"]
addtodb = subprocess.Popen(addcmd)
```

Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Approach 3 looks broadly correct, but you almost certainly don't want to "quote" the URL, need to provide the correct script path, and want to pass a single list to `Popen`. Try:

```
addcmd = ["/usr/bin/perl", "../perl/bin/engine.pl", "--uid", str(our_id), "--url", source_url]
addtodb = subprocess.Popen(addcmd)
```

Update: incorporated fix from @AJefferiss

There seems to be an underlying misconception here around how program arguments are handled.

A command shell determines program arguments by *parsing* user input -- typically splitting on spaces (except where enclosed in quotes). In contrast, the underlying APIs like `Popen` accept a list of arguments directly.

The upshot is that when using such APIs 1) you don't need the quotes, and 2) you need to drop extra spaces around arguments. It's also why you can't (generally) use shell syntax like `~`, wildcard expansion or environment variables.

Comment: The perl script wants the URL to be quoted, but I tried it both ways, and neither work. I've updated the question with the error that #3 generates.

Comment: I spotted a couple of other potential problems

Comment: Good catches (1) I changed the path to "../perl/bin/engine.pl" and (2) removed the []'s from the POpen command --now, it's back to executing the perl script, but still isn't passing the arguments...

Comment: I'm fairly sure you need to remove the spaces around your arguments, so `addcmd = ["/usr/bin/perl", "engine.pl", "--uid", str(our_id), "--url", source_url]`

Comment: Did you try without the quotes? They're only needed when running from the command line. Speaking of which, does the perl script work as expected when you run it from the command line?

Comment: Perl script does work when I run it from the command line using the exact arguments, with the quotes, which are required because sometimes the URL's we're working with have spaces in them.

Comment: The combined answer is now working. Thank you both!!

Comment: Based on the note from [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) if you need to quote source url it should be a single list element.